# Viewport for IPAD

Tags: javascript, viewport

Below is my code.

```
<script>
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null && window.matchMedia("(max-resolution: 264dpi)").matches) {
            document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0, width=1024">');
        } else {
            document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">');
        }
    </script>
```

Now if i open my webpage in IPAD portrait view, it is showing the landscape view of 1024px width. But expected view is portrait view only should come.

Please help me to sort out what is the issue in my above code.

Comment: portrait width is [768](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=ipad). If you use [media queries](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/) you can use the `orientation` flag to set other styles, too.

Comment: We are having media quries. But in ipad portrait view, the media quries are not loading because of this meta tag width. What needs to changed here what needs to be added here?